# When merge videos with animation using AVFoundation, how to maintain the total length of videos?

Tags: ios, swift, video, avfoundation, video-processing

I implemented this function based on
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/AVCustomEdit/Introduction/Intro.html

Here is my code:

```
 let muComposition = AVMutableComposition()
 let muVideoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition.init(propertiesOf: muComposition)
 var comVideoTracks = [AVMutableCompositionTrack]()

 for _ in 0...1 {
   comVideoTracks.append(muComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .video, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)!)
 }

 var passThroughTimeRanges: [CMTimeRange] = []
 var transitionTimeRanges: [CMTimeRange] = []
 var nextClipStartTime = CMTime.zero

 for (index,asset) in clips.enumerated() {
   guard let oriVideoTrack = (asset.tracks(withMediaType: .video).first) else { continue }
   let comVideoTrack = comVideoTracks[index % 2]
   let clipRange = clipRanges[index]
  
   try? comVideoTrack.insertTimeRange(clipRange, of: oriVideoTrack, at: nextClipStartTime)
   let duration = clipRange.duration
   passThroughTimeRanges.append(CMTimeRangeMake(start: nextClipStartTime, duration: duration))
   if index > 0 {
    passThroughTimeRanges[index].start = CMTimeAdd(passThroughTimeRanges[index].start, trasitionTime)
    passThroughTimeRanges[index].duration = CMTimeSubtract(passThroughTimeRanges[index].duration, trasitionTime)
   }
   if index + 1 < clips.count {
    passThroughTimeRanges[index].duration = CMTimeSubtract(passThroughTimeRanges[index].duration, trasitionTime)
   }
   nextClipStartTime = CMTimeAdd(nextClipStartTime, duration)
   nextClipStartTime = CMTimeSubtract(nextClipStartTime, trasitionTime)
   if index + 1 < clips.count {
     let transitionTimeRange = CMTimeRange(start: nextClipStartTime, duration: trasitionTime)
     transitionTimeRanges.append(transitionTimeRange)
  }
}
var instructions: [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction] = []
for (index,asset) in clips.enumerated() {
  let comVideoTrack = comVideoTracks[index % 2]
  let passThroughInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
  passThroughInstruction.timeRange = passThroughTimeRanges[index]
  let passThroughLayer = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: comVideoTrack)
  changeVideoSize(asset: asset,passThroughLayer: passThroughLayer)
  passThroughInstruction.layerInstructions = [passThroughLayer]
  instructions.append(passThroughInstruction)
  
  if index + 1 < clips.count{
    let transitionInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
    let transitionTimeRange = transitionTimeRanges[index]
    transitionInstruction.timeRange = transitionTimeRange
    let fromLayer =
                    AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: comVideoTrack)
    let toLayer =
                    AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack:comVideoTracks[1 - index % 2])
    
    changeVideoSize(asset: asset, passThroughLayer: fromLayer)
    changeVideoSize(asset: clips[index + 1],passThroughLayer: toLayer)
 
    if index % 2 == 1 {
      fromLayer.setOpacityRamp(fromStartOpacity: 1.0, toEndOpacity: 0.0, timeRange: transitionTimeRange)
      toLayer.setOpacityRamp(fromStartOpacity: 0.0, toEndOpacity: 1.0, timeRange: transitionTimeRange)
    }
  }
  
  transitionInstruction.layerInstructions = [fromLayer, toLayer]
  instructions.append(transitionInstruction)
 }
}

 muVideoComposition.instructions = instructions
```

These videos are between five and ten seconds long. After I processed 70 videos the total length of the video was eventually shortened based on the transition time.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Where does a guy named 'clipRanges' come from?

Comment: @ElTomato clips is [AVAsset].
clipRanges = clips.map { CMTimeRange(start: CMTime.zero, duration: $0.duration) }